# Microsoft Azure Runbook not executing powershell script

Tags: azure, powershell-v3.0

I'm trying to run the powershell script below in Micrososft Azure runbooks. However, I keep on getting the error:

[image: error]

The script is as follows:

```
#### Provide the computer name in $computername variable

$ServerName = "testauto","LocalHost","Server-2","Not-Exists", "Fake-computer", "Dc-1" 

##### Script Starts Here ###### 

foreach ($Server in $ServerName) {

            if (test-Connection -ComputerName $Server -Count 2 -Quiet ) { 

                  write-Host "$Server is alive and Pinging " -ForegroundColor Green

                              } else

                              { Write-Warning "$Server seems dead not pinging"

                              }      

}
```

The script runs ok within Powershell ISE, but not in Microsoft Azure Automation Runbooks.

Can someone please let me know why?

Cheers

Carlton

Comment: I've tested this out and get the same error. I would suspect there is some sort of restriction in Azure Automation that prevents this running, but I'm not clear on what yet. I assume you are running this on standard workers, not hybrid ones?

Comment: Hi Sam, thanks for responding..yes, I running on standard workers, not hybrid ones

Comment: Sam, the problem that was occurring with the link from the site you provided was due to administrator wanting to connect to on-premise site. My situation is within the same Vnet.

Comment: @MichaelBrown did you mean to direct that at @carltonp?

Comment: @Sam Cogan, yes I did sorry.

Answer (score 0):

**The `Test-Connection` is not installed in Azure Automation by default, so you could not use the cmdlet.**

You could import a module from the Automation Module Gallery with the Azure portal. More information please refer to this [article](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-runbook-gallery#modules-in-powershell-gallery).

Comment: Walter, thanks for the link. I had been checking that out. Unfortunately, the resolution wasn't to be found on that site

Comment: The problem appears to be with this line of code: RunbookFlow : The specified service does not exist as an installed service. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070424)
At line:7 char:57

Comment: @Carltonp I update my answer. I test in my lab. It works for me.

Comment: Hi Walter, this is looking promising. I can't test at the moment as I'm having a problem with my azure account. As soon as its fixed I'll try the solution. Cheers

Comment: Hi Walter, I have finally got my account working. Going to try your suggestion now.. I will keep you posted. Cheers

Comment: Hi Walter, I have the AzureRM.Websites, and I found the cmdlet Test-Connection, but I still get the error message : test-Connection : The specified service does not exist as an installed service I'm not sure how you managed to get it working

Comment: @Carltonp Sorry for my mistake, I test other cmdlet `Set-AzureRmAppServicePlan` , it works.  
Just recentlyI, test `Test-Connection`, it does not work for me too. Maybe you could try to use `TestConnectionAsync `.